# Gphoto2 macos burst mode

Tags: macos, eos, libgphoto2

Actually im preparing to solar total eclipse in the USA, and I'm trying to automate taking a photo of the sun. The problem is, there is only one program available for macOS (CaptureEclipse) which does not meet my requirements. As an alternative, I would like to write a python script to capture images: using a gphoto2 lib, or just call terminal commands of gphoto2. Anyway, there is a big problem, gphoto2 takes picture once a more than 1 sec. My camera is canon EOS R, and I know that Canon has in their SDK possibility to taking a photo faster: on the program CaptureEclipse there is a burst mode. The question is, how to capture a picture in burst mode on gphoto2? WHat i have tried and it didnt work:
`sudo gphoto2 --capture-image --set-config capturemode='Burst' --set-config burstnumber=5`

Answer (score 0):

Running this should work:

```
gphoto2 --set-config eosremoterelease="2" --wait-event=1s --set-config eosremoterelease="4"
```